# Rename a column in kdb q

Tags: kdb

How to rename a column from TotalPercent  to "%"

| TotalPercent |
| --- |
| 98 |
| 87 |

to output as

| % |
| --- |
| 98 |
| 87 |

in kdb q

Comment: [q] is not the right tag for this question - use tags [kdb] or [q-lang] instead. [Post on Meta Stackoverflow, posted today](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/426592/rename-q-to-q-js-to-avoid-confusion-with-q-lang?cb=1)

Answer (score 5):

While you can do this in kdb with `xcol` it would not be advisable to do so.

```
q)tab:([]TotalPercent:98 87)
q)(`$"%") xcol tab
%
--
98
87
```

We can see this by making the change permanent, then trying to select which results in an error:

```
q)tab:(`$"%") xcol tab
q)select % from tab
'rank
  [0]  select % from tab
       ^
```

To select from this table you would have to use functional form:

```
q)?[tab;();0b;{x!x}enlist`$"%"]
%
--
98
87
```

It is advisable to steer clear of special characters like this in column names as they are not easy to work with an could cause confusion for other developers.

Using `%` specifically will cause confusion with the divide operator.

The only valid reason to do so may be simply for printing the result.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xcol` which expects a list of symbols. You can put special characters into a string and convert the string to a symbol like

```
(`$"%") xcol ([] TotalPercent: 98 87)
```